How to find these series sums considering the Fourier series of $\cos(\frac{x}{2})$
I was first asked to develop the Fourier series of $\cos(\frac{x}{2})$ which came out to be:
$$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sim\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{\pi\left(n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}\cdot\cos\left(nx\right)$$
now I was asked to find the following sums using said series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}}\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}}$$
the right sum seemed easy enough, I checked that there's pointwise convergence for the values of $\pm \pi,0$ but then depending on the approach I got two different results:
for $x=0$:
$$1=\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{\pi\left(n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
$$2-\pi =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
I moved the free term to the left side, multiplied by $\pi$ and divided by $-1$, but for $x=\pm\pi$:
$$0=\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{\pi\left(n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}\cdot\left(-1\right)$$
$$-2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
so clearly something in my way has gone wrong, also for the non-alternating sum I have no idea how to achieve it; I know I should find some $x$ for which the $\cos(nx)=-1$ for odd values of $n$ only (so for even $n$ it would be $0$) but I can't think of any.

$\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$

$$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sim\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi(n^{2}-1/4)}\cos(nx)$$
When $x=0$ you have:
$$ 1=\frac2{\pi}+\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}-1/4}=\frac2{\pi}-\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}-1/4}$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}-1/4}=\pi\left(\frac2{\pi}-1\right) =2-\pi.$$
For the other sum, note that $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$, so plugging in $x=\pi$ leads to
$$0=\frac2{\pi}-\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-1/4}(-1)^n=\frac2{\pi}-\frac1{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1/4} $$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1/4}=2. $$

I see, so I needed to consider $\pm\pi$ to actually be $\pm\pi +2k\pi$ this way in the second sum I would get instead of the cos term on the sum another $(-1)^n$ that would cancel with the other one.

@Nate3384 yes, it's sufficient to consider $x=\pi$

Consider the identity $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-a^{2}}=\frac{1}{2\,a^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2\,a}\cot(\pi\,a)$$ valid for non-integer $a$. Setting $a=\tfrac12$ gives $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}-\tfrac14}=\tfrac{1}{2\cdot(\tfrac14)}-\pi\,\cot\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\bigr).$$ Since $\cot\bigl(\tfrac{\pi}{2}\bigr)=0$, the sum is $2$. For the alternating sum, one may replace $\cot(\pi z)$ with $\csc(\pi z)$ to handle the factor $(-1)^n=e^{i\pi n}$ via a complex analysis approach or by known expansions of $\pi\csc(\pi z)$. A direct route is to check numerically that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\bigl[n^2-\tfrac14\bigr]^{-1}$$ hovers near $2-\pi$. When one defines the function $$F(z)=\tfrac{\pi\,z\,e^{i\pi z}}{z^2-\tfrac14}$$ and sums its principal parts in the complex plane, the residues at integer $z=n$ match $(-1)^n\bigl[n^2-\tfrac14\bigr]^{-1}$. Evaluating the integral of $F(z)$ around large contours shows these residues add to $2-\pi$, matching direct partial-sum approximations. Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-\tfrac14}=2-\pi$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-\tfrac14}=2.$$​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
